# Как одному обьекту одного класса присвоить два обьекта другого класса?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте такой вопрос, как одному обьекту одного класса присвоить два обьекта другого класса.
Допустим у меня есть два класса хозяин и собака

class Master{

};

class Dog{

};

Вот как мне к одному хозяину сразу привязать две собаки ?

Answer (score 2):

С помощью отношения *СОДЕРЖИТ*. Например:

```
class Master
{
    vector<Dog> dogs;
};
```

и добавляйте собак, сколько угодно. Если они должны быть где-то сами по себе, а не только у хозяина - например, через вектор интеллектуальных указателей `shared_ptr`...

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
class Dog{

};

class Master{
public:
    std::vector<Dog> dogs;
};

//....

Master master;

Dog dog1, dog2;

mester.dogs.push_back(dog1);
mester.dogs.push_back(dog2);
```

Comment: Только это будут клонированные собаки :)

Comment: используйте emplace_back, move или другие способы